# ListView Item Source is null on initialization

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am trying to use a filter for a ListView upon  and on initialization, the project is throwing a Null Pointer for the ListView, even though I am setting it in the Constructor and the binding. Here is my code:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var viewModel = new MainViewModel();
            this.ProjectListView.ItemsSource = viewModel.Projects;
```

And here is the XAML that refernces it.

```
<ListView x:Name="ProjectListView" Margin="0,0,10,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" FontSize="16" Foreground="Black">
```

I am not sure why the ItemSource is null if it is initialized in the Constructor. Is there a PropertyChanged binding I need to apply?

Here's most of my XAML

```
  <TextBox x:Name="FolderNameBox" Grid.Column="1" Background="White" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" 
               Margin="0,0,287,654.333" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
               Padding="6" FontSize="16"
               IsReadOnly="True"
               Text="{Binding ElementName=Hierarchy, Path=SelectedItem.Path, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}">
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="SearchProjectsBox" Grid.Column="5" Background="White" Grid.Row="1" Text="Search Projects"
        Margin="47.333,0,0,654.333" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="LightGray" Padding="6" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="268" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" TextChanged="FilterListView"/>
    <TreeView x:Name="Hierarchy" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="631" Margin="0,58,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="226" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Projects}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildFolders}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5"></Image>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="16" Margin="5" IsReadOnly="True" PreviewMouseDoubleClick="SelectAll" LostFocus="TextBoxLostFocus"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
    <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="631" Margin="245,58,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="540">
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <ListView x:Name="ProjectListView" Margin="0,0,10,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" FontSize="16" Foreground="Black">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

ANd heres my base View Model

```
        private ObservableCollection<Project> projects;
    public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects
    {
        get { return projects; }
        set
        {
            if (value != projects)
            {
                projects = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Projects");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the Code Behind

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainViewModel();
            MainViewModel model = new MainViewModel();
            model.BuildData();
            this.ProjectListView.ItemsSource = model.Projects;

        }

        private void FilterListView(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ProjectListView.ItemsSource).Refresh();
        }
```

FilterListView is the TextChange method. It breaks on the first line. ProjectListVIew is registering as null but it shouldn't even be launched because it is dependent on a change in the TextBox.

Edit. Here's the code behind

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainViewModel();
            MainViewModel model = new MainViewModel();
            model.BuildData();
            this.ProjectListView.ItemsSource = model.Projects;

        }

        private void FilterListView(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ProjectListView.ItemsSource).Refresh();
        }


        private void SelectAll(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox box = sender as TextBox;
            box.IsReadOnly = false;
            box.SelectAll();
        }

        private void TextBoxLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox box = sender as TextBox;
            box.IsReadOnly = true;
        }

        private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
            tb.Text = string.Empty;
            tb.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
            tb.GotFocus -= TextBox_GotFocus;
        }

        private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox box = (TextBox)sender;
             box.Text = "Search Projects";
             box.Foreground = Brushes.LightGray;
             box.GotFocus += TextBox_GotFocus;  
        }
    }
}
```

Base View Model

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string projectName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(projectName));
        }
    }
    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

And the View Model I am using

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Project> projects;
    public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects
    {
        get { return projects; }
        set
        {
            if (value != projects)
            {
                projects = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Projects");
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

My ListView constantly changes - as in, the data shown will be based on a User's selection in a TreeView. Right now, my filter doesn't take into consideration what is actually on the screen. It is only filtering based on the binded Collection.

So if my Collection is Fruit, Vegetables, Meat, Dairy and my ListView is Apple, Carrot, and Milk, if I search Apple, the ListView will be blank but if I search Fruit, I will have a populated row. Not correcty, clearly.

Sounds like I am fairly close.

This is my View Model:

```
public ICollectionView SourceCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return this.projectCollection.View;
        }
    }

    public string FilterText
    {
        get
        {
            return filterText;
        }
        set
        {
            filterText = value;
            this.projectCollection.View.Refresh();
            RaisePropertyChanged("SearchProjectsText");
        }
    }

    private void projectCollection_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterText))
        {
            e.Accepted = true;
            return;
        }

        Project project = e.Item as Project;
        if (project.Name.ToUpper().Contains(FilterText.ToUpper()) || project.Path.ToUpper().Contains(FilterText.ToUpper()))
        {
            e.Accepted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Accepted = false;
        }
    }

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Where SearchProjectText is the actual TextBox used for filtering. My relevant XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SearchProjectsBox" Grid.Column="5" Background="White" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding FilterText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Margin="47.333,0,0,654.333" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Padding="6" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="268"/>
    <TreeView x:Name="Hierarchy" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="631" Margin="0,58,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="226" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Projects}">

<ListView x:Name="ProjectListView" Margin="0,0,10,0" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceCollection}" FontSize="16" Foreground="Black">
```

Comment: You're newing up the `MainViewModel` but `viewModel.Projects` may still be `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set the datacontext. Don't both bind and assign; you don't need both. Just set the DataContext of the parent, and bind the appropriate parent property in the XAML (which you already did -- your XAML looks fine):

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
```

And make sure your viewmodel properly raises `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` when you assign a new collection instance to its `Projects` property.

And make sure you *do* give Projects a collection, and that there's something in it.

You're using `ObservableCollection<T>` I hope, not `List<T>`, for the collection?

### Update

I don't know why (it's late and I'm tired, sorry!), but `FilterListView` is getting called before `InitializeComponent()`. I should've thought of that when you described the symptoms. This fixes it for me:

```
private void FilterListView(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ProjectListView != null)
    {
        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ProjectListView.ItemsSource).Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, Projects is an Observable. The main goal I am trying to do is use a filtering mechanism on a TextBox. The problem is, the List view is empty on load and only is populated when the user makes a selection on a TreeView so it's very complicated.

Comment: Shouldn't be *that* complicated. You need to show us the part with the CollectionViewSource too. Is that in XAML or in the viewmodel?

Comment: I added some of my XAML and the VM

Comment: Where's the CollectionViewSource? What about the null ref exception in your text changed handler? What's null there? Put in a breakpoint, see what's going on.

Comment: When I call the Refresh button, it breaks. The Text CHanged method was CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ListView.ItemsSource).Refresh();

Comment: It's ProjectListView, which is the name of my ListView. I don't understand why it is null, though, especially when I set the ItemsSource in the constructor. I am wondering why this method is getting called automatically. It's a TextChange method - it should only be fired when the text changes yet it's being fired automatically.

Comment: I can't debug code I can't see. This is almost certainly a fairly trivial issue, if I had code to reproduce it. Is `ProjectListView` really seriously null? Is it actually in your main window? That's bizarre, if true. I need to see enough code to reproduce this.

Comment: Yeah, it's in my main window and null. I added the base constructor. THe List VIew is empty until the user makes a TreeView selection. It's blank on load-up. Well, the container that holds it is there..a Grid..maybe the ListView is not there on load-up..

Comment: I added more code and the XAML was posted above. I hope it's not something trivial..I wish it was something more complicated so I don't feel so dumb

Comment: I've been doing this for a living since 1996 and feeling dumb doesn't bother you at all after the first decade or so.

Comment: @Arrayoob See update. It's, well... not very complicated :)

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the null problem. The filtering still doesn't work, unfortunately. It just jumps right to the first folder's top level.

Comment: I'll take a look tomorrow; it's late here. Or you could ask another question.

Comment: Thank you, will do. I am getting this error. System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'TreeViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for your help.You put me in the right spot.

Comment: @Arrayoob Right on.

Comment: Actually, I have a small bug. If you have time, could you see my newest edit?

Answer (score 0):

set the DataContext that will create a new instance of the ViewModel it's binding to.

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   DataContext = new MainViewModel();
 }
```

Comment: I am still getting a null exception with my TextChanged method for a TextBox which is CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ListViewItemsSource).Refresh();